# SQL Join Statement To Update an Entire Column with PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update an entire column with new unique phone numbers that live in a second table. I seem to be on the right track... but my loop logic is faulty.

I'm returning the matches correctly as far as I can tell, but when I try to update the entire column in the table it inserts the last phone number in every single row.

```
$query = "SELECT matched.duns, matched.new_p1, users_data.temp_duns
          FROM matched 
          INNER JOIN users_data ON temp_duns
          WHERE temp_duns = duns LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

foreach ($result as $key => $val) { 
        if($val['duns'] === $val['temp_duns']) {
            $final_query = "UPDATE users_data SET phone_number = " . $val['new_p1'];
            $final_result = mysqli_query($connection, $final_query);        
            echo $counter . "DUNS From matched: " . $val['duns'] . " DUNS From users_data: " . $val['temp_duns'] .  " NEW PHONE: ".  $val['new_p1']. "<br>";
        }       
    }
```

I'm a total newb but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run an update query in one call without looping and in MySQL `INNER JOIN` can be used:

```sql
UPDATE user_data u
INNER JOIN matched m ON u.temp_duns = m.temp_duns
SET u.phone_number = m.new_p1;
```

Or for the limit of 10:

```sql
UPDATE user_data u
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM matched LIMIT 10) m ON u.temp_duns = m.temp_duns
SET u.phone_number = m.new_p1;
```

Comment: Yes...I wound doing something similar...just using SQL and dropping the php loop.  I had to go and change a few things in one of the tables, but I wound up with a simple  SQL that worked.                                                               UPDATE users_data
INNER JOIN dummytable
ON dummytable.user_id = users_data.user_id
SET users_data.phone_number = dummytable.phone_num

Comment: Great! You know your data at end of day. If solution helped, please accept (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, so it's updating every row.

`"UPDATE users_data SET phone_number = " . $val['new_p1'];`

You need to limit it to just the row that you want to update.

`"UPDATE users_data SET phone_number = " . $val['new_p1'] . " WHERE some_id = " . $some_id;`

You could probably do the whole thing in a single query.

`UPDATE table_to_be_updated
JOIN table_with_value_we_need ON whatever_joins_them
SET table_to_be_updated.column_we_want_to_fill = table_with_value_we_need.value_we_need;`

Comment: Yes, I actually added the where clause right after posting this question and it didn't work.  The problem was on my part and my tables..... but in the end I did just use a simple sql statement without a loop and it worked. Thanks